# FireMonkey TransitionEffect not respecting aspect ratio

Tags: delphi, animation, transition, firemonkey

I'm experimenting with a small FireMonkey application to browse images and I'm using a TBlurTransitionEffect to transition from one image to the next.  But my only problem with it is that the effect does not seem to respect the aspect ratio of the TImage control that I'm using it on.  My TImage has a wrap mode of iwFit, but the transition behaves as though it were set to iwStretch.

The application is basically a form with a TListBox filled with image file names and a TImage with a TBlurTransitionEffect attached (with a TFloatAnimation acting on its progress property).  The code looks like the following

```
procedure TForm4.FloatAnimation1Finish(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(BlurTransitionEffect1.Target);
end;

procedure TForm4.ListBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BlurTransitionEffect1.Target.LoadFromFile(PicPath + ListBox1.Selected.Text);
  FloatAnimation1.Start;
end;
```

I was wondering if the was a simple solution to this, I suspect that I'm going to have to add white borders to the images to make them the same aspect ratio as the TImage.